# Bad luck and superstitions

Tags: sin

One thing I feel like no body touches on is, myth folklore superstition when i say those three categories I’m talking about like superstitions as black cats, the number 13th and things like breaking a mirror is 7 years of bad luck, is anything mentioned in the Quran that does away with these superstitions? Thank you very much to anyone who answers or reads this :)

Answer (score 0):

Bismillah hir rahman nir raheem as sallamu alaykum akhi al kareem
In bukhari ibn abbas said the prophet Muhammad صلى الله عليه وسلم said "seventy thousand will enter Paradise without being brought to account.’” Then he  went inside, without explaining further. The people started to discuss what he had said, saying, “We are the ones who have believed in Allaah and followed His Messenger; we are they” or, “It is our children who were born in Islam whilst we were born in Jaahiliyyah.” The Prophet heard about what was being said, so he came out and said: “They are the ones who do not seek ruqya, do not believe in bad omens and do not use branding; they put their trust in their Lord…”

Point here is those who do not believe in bad omens some scholars say this means superstitions.